# How do I make a new line from text created by the script

Tags: javascript, html

```
I'm trying to make a part of my website where you click on a title and then the description pops up and it works but I don't know how to add a new line/bullet points for it 

I've tried \n and that didn't work.

<body>

<button class = "text_buttons" type = "button" id = "Toast" onclick="myFunction()">Purpose▼</button>
<p id="cheese"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
    if (document.getElementById("Toast").innerHTML =="Purpose▼") document.getElementById("Toast").innerHTML = "Purpose▲";
    else document.getElementById("Toast").innerHTML ="Purpose▼";

    if (document.getElementById("cheese").innerHTML == "") document.getElementById("cheese").innerHTML = "This is not what is actually displayed but it's jsut filler text that hopefully i can figure out to space correctly";
    else document.getElementById("cheese").innerHTML = "";
}
</script>
</body>
```

No errors occur, I just can't seem to get this. I've tried looking at some stuff online but the only one I found was the one that suggested \n but that wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: can make your code a snippet ( by hitting the little image that has <>) so that i can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

As for the new line issue, in HTML, the `<br>` tag is used as a line break. `\n` is used in scripts, but won't work here. If you're trying to use bullet points, the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags for unordered lists will help you do that.

```
<body>

<button class = "text_buttons" type = "button" id = "Toast" onclick="myFunction()">Purpose▼</button>
<p id="cheese"></p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
    if (document.getElementById("Toast").innerHTML =="Purpose▼") document.getElementById("Toast").innerHTML = "Purpose▲";
    else document.getElementById("Toast").innerHTML ="Purpose▼";

    if (document.getElementById("cheese").innerHTML == "") document.getElementById("cheese").innerHTML = "This is a line<br>and another line<br>oh more lines<ul><li>And this is a bullet point<ul><li>And a nested bullet point</li></ul></li></ul>";
    else document.getElementById("cheese").innerHTML = "";
}
</script>
</body>
```

This can lead so some pretty messy code, though. Template engines can help you when inserting pieces of HTML repeatedly.